# Using a pipe to filter an array of objects by an array of strings in Angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, web, angular2-pipe

I am attempting to filter an array of objects which have a similar structure to this:

```
posts = [
 {
  title: 'post 1 title',
  location: 'Location 1'
 },
 {
  title: 'post 2 title',
  location: 'Location 2'
 },
 {
  title: 'post 3 title',
  location: 'Location 3'
 }
]
```

I am filtering this array of objects (above) with an array of strings (below)

```
locations = [
 'Location 1',
 'Location 2',
 'Location 3'
]
```

How it should be working:I enter into a 'tag' style input box in the browser as many locations as I want and it should display the posts with location properties matching those location 'tags' in the locations array.

All the posts are initially displayed (which is good), then when I enter tags I am able to get the filtered objects in the log which shows that they seem to be getting filtered based on my inputs. but the html in which the posts are looped through does not show the relevant posts.

I am using firebase to store the posts, and calling my service which returns all the posts on `ngOnInit()`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._tags = [];
    this._postService.getAllPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this._posts = posts;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
 <!--input *edited some stuff out like the add tag function. 'term' model gets pushed into the _tags array on enter or click etc-->
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="term [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

<!--tag list, shows tags that have been searched-->
<div class="tag" *ngFor="let t of _tags">{{t}}</div>

<!filtered post list-->
<div *ngFor="let post of _posts | tagsearchfilter:_tags">
  <h4>{{post.title}}</h4> 
</div>
...
```

Pipe filter:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../../services/post/post.service';

@Pipe({
    name: 'tagsearchfilter'
})

export class TagSearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(posts: any, tags: any): any {
        let rposts = [];
        if (tags === undefined || tags.length === 0 ) {
            return posts;
        }
        posts = posts.filter(function(post){
            tags.forEach(tag => {
                if (
                    post.location.toLowerCase().includes(tag.toLowerCase())
                ) {
                    rposts.push(post);
                    console.log('Post location: ' + post.location + ' Tag: ' + tag);
                }
            });
            posts = rposts;
            console.log(posts);
            return posts;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea. Angular 2 doesn't have a filter pipe on purpose, because it's too slow to use a pipe to do this. Just create a filtered copy of your array each time a tag is added or removed, and iterate on the filtered array. Also, your method adds the same posts twice if it has two tags, and that's not how the filter() method of arrays works: its callback is supposed to return a boolean, indicating if the current post should be included in the filtered array or not: `const filteredPosts = posts.filter(post => hasOneOfTheTags(post))`.

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-.

Comment: In additon to what @JBNizet said , on each change detected or asynchronous call in your app angular will execute the filter even the tags remain the same, to see it in action add a `console.log("hi")` in your filter and write a `setInterval(()=>{},200)` in your ngOnInit and see how many times `hi` will appear in the console.

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine that's only for pure pipes. Normal pipes are only called when the passed value or parameters change (for arrays and objects if different instances are passed - content changes are ignored).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think you want to say ' that's only for impure pipes ' because normal pipes are pure by default. what I said apply only on impure pipes ,see it in action here https://plnkr.co/edit/LwZEFG , I was wrong ,thanks for your reply

Comment: Sorry for my confusing comment, yes you are right, I meant only for impure pipes

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, I put something together based on your answer!